# Diagnosing a NoMethodError that's occurring outside my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, mapmyfitness

I'm using [omniauth](http://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth) and [omniauth-mapmyfitness-oauth2](http://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-mapmyfitness-oauth2) to allow MapMyFitness users to sign in to my site.

Recently, I've had a few sign in attempts result in the error below. It doesn't look like any of the error is occurring in my Rails app's code - it seems like it's entirely within ruby, some gem(s), or the MapMyFitness API.

Any direction/information/suggestions on how to debug this **at all** would be greatly appreciated. I haven't experienced an issue like this before, so it's a huge learning opportunity.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass):
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1435:in `block in initialize_http_header'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1433:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1433:in `initialize_http_header'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1862:in `initialize'
  faraday (0.8.9) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:55:in `new'
  faraday (0.8.9) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:55:in `create_request'
  faraday (0.8.9) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:75:in `perform_request'
  faraday (0.8.9) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:38:in `call'
  faraday (0.8.9) lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
  faraday (0.8.9) lib/faraday/connection.rb:253:in `run_request'
  oauth2 (0.9.3) lib/oauth2/client.rb:90:in `request'
  oauth2 (0.9.3) lib/oauth2/client.rb:135:in `get_token'
  oauth2 (0.9.3) lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:29:in `get_token'
  omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.2) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:93:in `build_access_token'
  omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.2) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:75:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:227:in `callback_call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.8.0.218) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.8.0.218) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.8.0.218) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3877922931106558540__call__1275774963243928783__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.16) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.16) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (3.1.16) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

I did poke into the `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb` file, and found a reference to `.strip` right at line 1435:

```
def initialize_http_header(initheader)
  @header = {}
  return unless initheader
  initheader.each do |key, value|
    warn "net/http: warning: duplicated HTTP header: #{key}" if key?(key) and $VERBOSE
    @header[key.downcase] = [value.strip]
  end
end
```

I don't know what to do with that information, though.

Comment: what are in the headers of your http request?

Comment: Do you know how I would obtain this information? The request (user_omniauth_authorize_url) is generated by either omniauth or omniauth-mapmyfitness-oauth2 - perhaps it's [this code](https://github.com/jcasimir/omniauth-mapmyfitness-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/mapmyfitness.rb)?

Comment: OH! That might be it! `ENV['MMF_API_KEY']` might not have been carried over in my recent server move!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[omniauth-mapmyfitness-oauth2](http://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-mapmyfitness-oauth2) has a weird requirement that `ENV['MMF_API_KEY']` be defined for the library to work. (Weird to me, anyway. I'd love to know more about why it was set up this way.)

This is because it's using that environment variable on [line 13 of its strategy file](https://github.com/jcasimir/omniauth-mapmyfitness-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/mapmyfitness.rb#L13).

I recently migrated the server, and forgot to bring along this environment variable. Based on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/389203/96935) I added two lines to a new file, `/etc/profile.d/mapmyfitness.sh`, to make this available system-wide:

```
export MMF_API_KEY=my-key
export MMF_API_SECRET=my-secret
```